# "false" text being inserted into my database

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have an insert statement with a number of DataGridViewComboBoxColumns. When I try and insert the values of these DataGridViewComboBoxColumns into my database the text "False" is being inserted into the fields.

Why is this happening?

```
Dim para As New SqlClient.SqlParameter
Dim dateValue As String = CStr(DateTimePicker1.Value)
Dim calendar = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(dateValue, 10)
para.ParameterName = "@company"
para.Value = company.Selected.ToString
para.ParameterName = "@division"
para.Value = division.Selected.ToString
para.ParameterName = "@date"
para.Value = DateTimePicker1.Value
para.ParameterName = "@supplier"
para.Value = supplier.Selected.ToString
para.ParameterName = "@material_group"
para.Value = materialGroup.Selected.ToString
para.ParameterName = "@cost"
para.Value = netprice.Selected.ToString
para.ParameterName = "@dsc"
para.Value = description.Selected.ToString
para.ParameterName = "@email"
para.Value = cmbEmail.SelectedValue
para.ParameterName = "@userID"
para.Value = id
para.ParameterName = "@Name"
para.Value = txtEmployee.Text
para.ParameterName = "@val"
para.Value = newName
para.ParameterName = "@quantity"
para.Value = quantity.Selected.ToString
para.ParameterName = "@wbs"
para.Value = wba.Selected.ToString
para.ParameterName = "@marketingCode"
para.Value = markCodes.Selected.ToString
para.ParameterName = "@hccNumber"
para.Value = hccNumber.Selected.ToString
para.ParameterName = "@currency"
para.Value = currency.Selected.ToString
```

Insert details:

```
Dim con As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
Dim myCommand As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@company", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30).Value = company.Selected.ToString
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@division", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30).Value = division.Selected.ToString
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30).Value = DateTimePicker1.Value
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@supplier", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30).Value = supplier.Selected.ToString
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@material_group", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30).Value = materialGroup.Selected.ToString
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@cost", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30).Value = netprice.Selected.ToString
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@dsc", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30).Value = description.Selected.ToString
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@email", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30).Value = cmbEmail.SelectedValue
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@userID", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30).Value = id
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30).Value = newName
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@quantity", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 40).Value = quantity.Selected.ToString
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@wbs", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 40).Value = wba.Selected.ToString
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@marketingCode", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 40).Value = markCodes.Selected.ToString
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@hccNumer", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 40).Value = hccNumber.ToString
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@currency", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 40).Value = currency.Selected.ToString

Dim myAdapter As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
Dim sql As String = "Insert into details (company, division, date, supplier, material_group, cost, dsc, email, userID, fullName, marketingCode, wbs, qty, currency) VALUES (@company, @division, @date, @supplier, @material_group, @cost, @dsc, @email, @userID, @Name, @marketingCode, @wbs, @quantity, @currency)"
myCommand.Connection = con
myCommand.CommandText = sql
myAdapter.InsertCommand = myCommand
myCommand.Connection.Open()
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
myCommand.Connection.Close()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are storing if something is selected.

```
para.Value = company.Selected.ToString
```

Selected is a boolean!

Comment: so should I have it as `company.tostring`   ?

Comment: yes, you have to use the variable of the control the value is stored in.

Comment: when I take out the .ToString I'm left with the value 'DataGridViewComboBoxColumn { N'  in my table. Do you by any chance know why this is?

Comment: You have to acces the .Value of the cell of the row you want to store. Like this "dataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[company.Name].Value;" A variable of type DataGridViewComboBoxColumn holds information about a certain column of the grid view.

Comment: with this piece of Code I get the error "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.Parameter name: index"     `myCommand.Parameters.Add("@company", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30).Value = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(company.Name)`

Comment: You asked "Why is this happening?" - this is your answer. If you have another question, you should ask it separately just so anyone coming back here to reference this isn't digging through all of these comments to see what's going on. Don't forget to upvote and accept, Mr. 50%. =)

Comment: @user765942: Yatrix is right: it would be nice, if you accept answers and ask your further questions in other threads (Everybody will try to help you) This board is organized in that way [faq]

Comment: thanks for the feedback guys, im still only learning how to use this site!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not certain on what you are trying to achieve here, but I don't think this script will work how you wish. You're not building a list of parameters with values, but replacing one parameter object over and over.

```
para.ParameterName = "@company"
para.Value = company.Selected.ToString
para.ParameterName = "@division"
para.Value = division.Selected.ToString
```

This will just first set the para object to be `@company`, and value: `company.Selected.ToString`, then set it again to be `@division` and value: `division.Selected.ToString`.

Your datatypes are all `NVarChar` and you are explicitly setting your `boolean` values to a string (`.ToString()`).

If you wish to store boolean values, change your data types to `bit`. Then change your values so you are passing the `boolean` value, not an explicitly converted `boolean` to `string`:

```
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@currency", SqlDbType.bit).Value = currency.Selected
```

Comment: Thanks, I dont wish to store boolean values, I wish to store strings, basically the selectedValue of the DataGridViewComboBoxColumn.

Answer (score 0):

company.selected returns true if the item is selected, and false if not...

You probably want to use company.ToString

Comment: when I take out the .ToString I'm left with the value 'DataGridViewComboBoxColumn { N' in my table. Do you by any chance know why this is?

Comment: -1: no it doesn't. It says that the column of the gridview is currently selected and company.ToString will serialize the type name DataGridViewColumn or something like this.